# Reducing joins by using a pivot instead?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on creating some views for my web application. I have separate tables that manage my emails and phones tables to my employees table. I'm trying to see if there is a way to reduce my large number of joins across these tables into a single pivot when much of the same information is coming from the same table.

My Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT emp.[first_name] as [First Name]
        ,emp.[last_name] as [Last Name]
        ,emp.[birth_day] as [Birthday]
        ,emp.[gender] as [Gender]
        ,emp.[address_line_1] as [Address]
        ,emp.[address_line_2] as [Apt/Suite #]
        ,emp.[city] AS [City]
        ,emp.[state] AS [State]
        ,emp.[zip] AS [Zip Code]
        ,phone1.[Home Phone Number]
        ,phone2.[Work Phone Number]
        ,phone3.[Mobile Phone Number]
        ,email1.[Primary Email]
        ,email2.[Secondary Email]
        ,email3.[Personal Email]

    FROM [employee].[employees] emp
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [phone_number] AS [Home Phone Number]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[phone_manager] 
    WHERE ([phone_type] = '1')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) phone1 ON phone1.employee_id = emp.employee_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [phone_number] AS [Work Phone Number]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[phone_manager] 
    WHERE ([phone_type] = '2')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) phone2 ON phone2.employee_id = emp.employee_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [phone_number] AS [Mobile Phone Number]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[phone_manager] 
    WHERE ([phone_type] = '3')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) phone3 ON phone3.employee_id = emp.employee_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [email] AS [Primary Email]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[email_manager] 
    WHERE ([email_type] = '1')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) email1 ON email1.employee_id = emp.employee_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [email] AS [Secondary Email]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[email_manager] 
    WHERE ([email_type] = '2')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) email2 ON email2.employee_id = emp.employee_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 [email] AS [Personal Email]
        ,[employee_id]
    FROM [employee].[email_manager] 
    WHERE ([email_type] = '3')
    ORDER BY [date_added] DESC
    ) email3 ON email3.employee_id = emp.employee_id
) pvt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want, on each "manager" table, by using `row_number()` and `group by`.  Here is an example for the phone numbers:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 and phone_type = 1 THEN phone_number END) as Home,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 and phone_type = 2 THEN phone_number END) as Work,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 and phone_type = 3 THEN phone_number END) as Mobile
FROM (SELECT employee_id, phone_number,
             row_number() over (partition by phone_type order by date_added desc) as seqnum
      FROM employee.phone_manager 
     ) ep
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

Comment: I also have a table called phone_types with the fields ID and Name respectively. Can I grab the column names via the name field when the ID matches?

Comment: @Jdsfighter . . . You could do it for a fixed set of phone types easily -- just join in the table and change the condition in the `WHEN` clause.  If you want a variable number of columns, that's a problem that would require dynamic SQL.